# Hide Chart axes but show labels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to hide the complete axes form a figure in Matlab.
However, I do want to show the xlabel.

Here's a workaround which worked at Matlab 2015a:

```
colormap(gray);
imagesc(-prog(:,:,fig));
xlabel(sprintf('c = %.2f',C(:,:,loop(fig))),'color','k')
axis equal; axis tight;
set(gca,'XTick',[],'YTick',[],'XTicklabel',[],...
        'YTicklabel',[],'xcolor','w','ycolor','w')
```

However, since 2015b and 2016a this doesn't work anymore, the xlabels are not shown in white (instead of black)

Comment: Thanks Suever,
new to stackexchange ;

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `xlabel` color *after* you change the `XColor` of the axes otherwise `set(gca, 'XColor', 'w')` forces everything to be white regardless of what you set it to previously.

```
figure(1)
C = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];
imagesc(C)

% Change axes colors and appearance
axis equal; axis tight;
set(gca,'XTick',[],'YTick',[],'XTicklabel',[],...
    'YTicklabel',[],'xcolor','w','ycolor','w') 

% NOW create your black xlabel
xlabel(sprintf('c = test'),'color','k')
```

[image]